# How do I kill the "server connections interrupted" window/process?

Tags: snow-leopard, network, finder

When my MacBook wakes up, away from a network it was previously connected to, it shows the "server connections interrupted" window. When I click "disconnect all", I get a spinning beach ball of death. Restarting the finder doesn't help. Logging out and restarting is not possible anymore. The only thing I can do is a hard reset.

Or is there a way to kill the process from the terminal or from the activity monitor?

Strange fact: when the interrupted connection window is beachballing, I'm also unable to invoke the 'About this mac...' command in the apple menu. Nothing happens...

[image: interrupted connections]

[image: unable to reopen the finder after force quit]

[image]

Comment: What kind of connections did you have before you disconnected?

Comment: What OS are you on? Mac OS 10.6 has much improved disk management than the previous versions.

Comment: I guess you are using DHCP, right? Some people report setting IP manually fixes the problem

Comment: My office and home networks use DHCP and the disconnection issue went away with the upgrade to 10.6.

Comment: Until we know the exact OS Version and the types of server connections he had before he slept his machine, it’s hard to tell.

Comment: I'm guessing he is using 10.6 since he tagged the question with "snow-leopard".

Comment: I'm using snow-leopard indeed. I have SMB connections to windows network share. I'm using admitmac and logging in with an Active Directory ID. I use DHCP. The server connections are truly interrupt, but the problem is that the disconnect all button gives me the spinning beach ball of death.

Comment: Is it just me, or does that first screenshot not look right? The eject icons look different, and there are usually two buttons at the bottom of the window instead of one.

Comment: @Nippy the disconnect window looks fine to me (tho the eject buttons seem to have a weird shadow). I didn’t see the Snow-leopard tag that’s why we were all asking :)

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is not common enough to find a solution on the [Apple Knowlegde Base](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&locale=en_US&q=) then it is most probably a rare issue caused by a corruption in the operating system or a 3'rd party application. Under these circumstances I would recommend one of the following:

- Reinstalling OS X (after performing a backup, preferably with [Time Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_%28software%29)).
- Find someone else with identical hardware and software to see if their laptop does the same thing under the same circumstances (might be a compatibility issue with your wireless access point or router?)
- Make a reservation at the [Apple Genius Bar](http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/), they are great troubleshooters and will be able to tell you if there is something wrong with your laptop hardware or software.
- A lot of troubleshooting information can be written to the [OS X Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28Mac_OS_X%29). Just have it running (and visible) while replicating this issue and it might print some information related to the issue.

I hope one of those steps can help you diagnose the issue, as it does not seem to be common enough to find a single solution for :-)

---

**UPDATE**: Since it appears that you are running "[ADMitMac](http://www.thursby.com/products/admitmac.html)" which probably integrates with OS X in a significant way, and considering your issues are network related, there is a rather large red flag surrounding this software. I would strongly recommend uninstalling it as a trial to diagnose the issues you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Good advice has already been given, however, in order to determine if there’s a **specific** share causing the issue, I’d suggest two things:

1) Create a new blank user, connect from there and try to see if this *new user* exhibits the same problem/behavior.

2) Additionally, disconnect all shares and start connecting one by one and perform the voodoo magic to reproduce the “disconnect” dialog (with each individual connection). That way you could see if the problem only manifests in some connections but not others, or all.

Do you have any server log or anything that could be an indication of a process hanging or waiting for a server response that never comes? (already suggested)

**UPDATE**: Today I made a test. I connected my 10.6.4 to a Samba box running an ancient version of Fedora (probably 3-4 years old). And when I had the connection open, I halted the server to get the Server connections interrupted dialog:

Here’s how my dialog looked like:

[image: Disconnect Dialog]

*public* is the name of the share and *nippur* is the name of the server.

Now that’s why your dialog looked weird. Are you sure you’re running 10.6.x?

**UPDATE 2**: You’re running 10.6.4 but using [ADMitMac](http://www.thursby.com/products/admitmac.html), which "turns a Mac into a true Active Directory client”. I suspect that’s where the problem lies. I’d disable or remove that and start from there. I’m 99% sure that without it, the problem will go away. The problem will then turn onto a new question… why? But that’s an entire new world and only Console Logs will help (plus, of course, ADMicMac’s tech support).

Comment: 1) My MacBook is brand new - using it since 1 week. 2) It happens with ALL server connections. 3) A server log is irrelevant, as I wake up my mac away from any servers.

Comment: What is not irrelevant is 2) Does it happen with ANY server connection? 3) By server connection I meant console output from YOUR computer.

Comment: "About this mac" says I'm running 10.6.4. I'm also forced to use ADMitMac, maybe that's why the eject button looks weird.

Comment: So, you are using Active Directory Mac (ADMitMac) and you have problems when you resume your Mac from sleep after being connected to (among other things) windows share on an Active Directory? I think you’ve found your answer. If it’s a brand new Macbook Pro with 10.6.4, I suggest you try a fresh install without ADMitMac and see from there. I suspect that that is the root of all evil here. Which would then turn the tables into talking to them about the issue. I don’t have that (nor a server) to try. I’m sure Console output could be helpful if you can capture some.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see your update before updating my answer ... I know it looks suspicious but I didnt copy you :)

Comment: @Nippysaurus It’s all good :)

Answer (score 1):

Try killing /System/Library/LoginPlugins/FSDisconnect.loginPlugin as described at http://whatsamknows.tumblr.com/post/37368603810/get-rid-of-server-connections-interrupted

Comment: Whilst your answer may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the article in an answer below, and provide the link for reference

Comment: even with sudo my mac won't allow me to move this directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are running 10.2 or 10.0 then what you are describing appears to be covered by the Apple Knowledge Base Article [TA21171 (Interruption of Server Connection Can Cause Computer to Stop Responding)](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21171). The solution they outline in the article:

> To resolve the issue, you may have to force restart your computer using the power or interrupt button.
>
> Avoid the issue in the future by ejecting any shared volumes before taking the actions described above.
>
> If you accidentally trigger this issue, restoring connectivity to the server might eliminate the need for a forced restart.

Comment: Nice research, but I doubt the OP (or anyone) is currently running 10.2. I believe most old Macs have Panther at least and those still having Jaguar are too old to even have problems :)

Comment: The solution is what I do now. But I want something other than force restart. Restoring connectivity is only possible if I travel back to the office. I'd rather force restart. :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had problems with disconnected network drives, but I have seen myself the Finder error -10810 and have always just restarted my Mac (saving all work beforehand).

[This](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2135129&tstart=0) thread here suggests though, that Finder will recover itself in a matter of few minutes so give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same problem. I get this aprox 75% of time when I wake my MacBook Pro from sleep. Everything works thou, so if I click share it's up and running. I guess my problem is related that network hasn't really woken up from sleep and therefore I get this annoying message dialog.

So my preferably solution would be that message box would be ignored. Does anyone know a way to do this? Or maybe shell script which would kill this message box..

I'm running 10.6.4 and not running any third party Active Directory or Network software

- Kriz